# Swift how to set custom accessory type or checkbox for specific cells programatically in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a UITableView containing cells which need different accessory types. At the moment I have the standard arrow accessory type from Swift. I want to set an accessory type or a checkbox at the right position inside the cell. How can I achieve this?

I have a ViewController class where I specify the information:

```
struct customCell {
        let title: String
} 

 func configure() {
            models.append(Section(title: "", options: [
             customCell(title: "Sounds"){
            },
}
```

And I have a different UITableViewCell class where I define whats needed:

```
private let label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.numberOfLines = 1
        return label
    }()
```

Right now it specifies the accessory type for all cells:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either add a checkbox in the Cell or use UITableViewCell `accessoryView`. For example:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        accessoryView = UISwitch()
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623219-accessoryview

Comment: I need different accessory types for specific cells. With your solution it changes the accessory types for all cells. Is there a way to specify it in: models.append(Section(title: "", options: [
             customCell(title: "Sounds"){
            },

Comment: You can set `accessoryView` in TableView DataSource. Something like this: ```override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   // Fetch a cell of the appropriate type.
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellTypeIdentifier", for: indexPath)
   
   // Configure the cell’s accessoryView.
 if model.cellType == .checkBox {
      cell.accessoryView = UISwitch()
    }
   return cell
}
```